# VHDL: check for result of zero fails

Tags: vhdl

I tried to check if the result of ALU is zero. I get a zero result from the test, but the simulation shows that `alu_zero` is not '1'. Could someone tell me why?

```
Library IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

ENTITY alu IS
 PORT(
  alu_operand_A,alu_operand_B:in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  alu_control:in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
  alu_result:out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  alu_zero:out std_logic
 );
END alu;

ARCHITECTURE behavioral OF alu IS
  signal s_alu_result:std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  BEGIN
  PROCESS(alu_operand_A,alu_operand_B,alu_control)
   BEGIN
   CASE alu_control IS
    WHEN "00"=>s_alu_result<=alu_operand_A + alu_operand_B;
               alu_result<=alu_operand_A + alu_operand_B;
    WHEN "01"=>s_alu_result<=alu_operand_A - alu_operand_B;
               alu_result<=alu_operand_A - alu_operand_B;
    WHEN "10"=>s_alu_result<=alu_operand_A and alu_operand_B;
               alu_result<=alu_operand_A and alu_operand_B;
    WHEN "11"=>s_alu_result<=alu_operand_A or alu_operand_B;
               alu_result<=alu_operand_A or alu_operand_B;
    WHEN OTHERS=>alu_result<=(others=>'X');
   END CASE;

  if s_alu_result="00000000000000000000000000000000" then
    alu_zero<='1';
  else
    alu_zero<='0';
  end if;
  END PROCESS;

END behavioral;
```

[image: screenshot reference]

Comment: Try putting s_alu_result in the process sensitivity list or create a concurrent conditional signal assignment to alu_zero instead of assigning it in the process or use a process variable as an intermediary variable for s_alu_result and test that for zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conceptional error in your code is, that signal assignments are not taking place immediately. Instead, if you do not specify a delay with an `after` clause, the new signal value is scheduled for the next delta cycle. But, the process is not executed again, because `s_alu_result` is not an the sensitivity list. Thus, `alu_zero` is not assigned to '1', because `s_alu_result` is still all 'U' at the check. The shortest fix would be, to add `s_alu_result` to the sensitivity list:

```
PROCESS(alu_operand_A,alu_operand_B,alu_control,s_alu_result)
```

---

For a better understanding, one can minimize the code even further by assigning a constant value of all '0' to signal `s_alu_result` and removing all unnecessary signals and assignment:

```
Library IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

ENTITY alu2 IS
  PORT(
    alu_zero : out std_logic
   );
END alu2;

ARCHITECTURE behavioral OF alu2 IS
  signal s_alu_result : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
BEGIN
  PROCESS
  BEGIN
    s_alu_result <= (others => '0');

    if s_alu_result="00000000000000000000000000000000" then
      alu_zero<='1';
    else
      alu_zero<='0';
    end if;

    wait;                               -- empty sensitivity list
  END PROCESS;
END behavioral;
```

The sensitivity list is empty now, so that, I have to insert a `wait;` statement at the end to mimin the correct behaviour. If you simulate this, `alu_zero` wil be '0' again, instead of '1'. The value all '0' is assigned to the signal `s_alu_result` for the next delta cycle. Thus, the check for all zero, still uses the old value which is all 'U'. Thus, the condition is false, and '0' is assigned to `all_zero`.

---

Further remarks:

- To get rid of the duplicate lines calculating `alu_result` and `s_alu_result`, you should assign `s_alu_result` first and then `alu_result <= s_alu_result` later.
- Do not use the non-standard VHDL package `std_logic_unsigned` from Synopsys. Use `numeric_std` instead. Then your operands must be of type `unsigned` instead of `std_logic_vector`, to indicate that the bit sequence should be treated as an unsigned number. Then you could also simplify the check for zero to: `s_alu_result = 0`.

The final code would look like this:

```
Library IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

ENTITY alu IS
 PORT(
  alu_operand_A : in  unsigned(31 downto 0);
  alu_operand_B : in  unsigned(31 downto 0);
  alu_control   : in  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
  alu_result    : out unsigned(31 downto 0);
  alu_zero      : out std_logic
 );
END alu;

ARCHITECTURE behavioral OF alu IS
  signal s_alu_result : unsigned(31 downto 0);
BEGIN
  PROCESS(alu_operand_A, alu_operand_B, alu_control, s_alu_result)
  BEGIN
    CASE alu_control IS
      WHEN "00"   => s_alu_result <= alu_operand_A + alu_operand_B;
      WHEN "01"   => s_alu_result <= alu_operand_A - alu_operand_B;
      WHEN "10"   => s_alu_result <= alu_operand_A and alu_operand_B;
      WHEN "11"   => s_alu_result <= alu_operand_A or alu_operand_B;
      WHEN OTHERS => s_alu_result <= (others => 'X');
    END CASE;

    alu_result <= s_alu_result;

    if s_alu_result = 0 then
      alu_zero <= '1';
    else
      alu_zero <= '0';
    end if;
  END PROCESS;

END behavioral;
```